# Unable to import raster data to postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis, raster

I have been trying to import my SRTM raster data into my postgis using the command, but has generated the following error (tried multiple times). Is there any thing missing? I appreciate for any help

Error message:

```
ERROR: relation "test" already exists
ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of textual material. Replace the image with a copy and paste of the error  messages. The error(where relation = table) is telling you what the problem is and this [raster2pgsql](https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html) provides the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

The error message says you're trying to create a relation that already exists. Either drop it in your database ..

```
DROP TABLE test;
```

.. or tell `raster2pgsql` to do it for your by adding the parameter `-d` to your command.

> -d  Drops the table, then recreates it and populates

Something like

```
raster2pgsql -I -z 10x10 -C -F -s 4326 file.hgt -d public.test | psql ...
```

An alterative is to use `-a` to append the data to an existing table

> -a  Appends raster into current table, must be exactly the same table schema.